# Make a column mandatory based on value of another column

Tags: calculated-column, list-form, validation

I have created an action list and when the status column is set to 'closed', I would like the 'date closed' column to automatically populate with the current date.  If this is not possible, it would be nice to make the 'date closed' column become a mandatory field.

Is this possible? And if so what would the formula be?

Comment: You could try this http://surpoint.blogspot.com.ar/2012/07/ocultar-columnas-en-base-al-valor-de.html

Comment: Thank you but I'm unable to change the code, so I need a calculate value formula or a column validation formula I think.

Comment: could I use date modified? for example if status = closed then the date closed column = last modified date?

Comment: Yes, modified is suported.

Comment: what would my formula be?  is this correct? =IF[Status]="Complete", [Date Closed]=[Date Modified]  and do I put this in a calculated value column or a date/time column?

Comment: Today is suported in validation. Modified in validation and calculated column

Comment: I think @Nisar proposed a good solution.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is a formula at list item validation. Go to list settings, and find  validation settings.

The formula you need to use should be something like the below one:

```
=IF([Status]="Closed",IF([Date Closed]=Today(),TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)
```

Instead of checking the [Date Closed] to be today only, you might want to just check `[Date Closed]>=Today()`. Or, if Today() doesn't work, you might want to compare for empty value by `[Date Closed]<>""`.

Note: List validations allow a field to be required depending on the value of onother field. Whith no code!

Comment: I think you are confusing list validation with calculated columns. And although I have never used this myself, I have seen some articles actually using this. For instance: https://www.premierpointsolutions.com/training/help-and-how-to-articles/how-to-validate-a-due-date-in-a-sharepoint-2010-list/ . Do you have any references to MSDN that says Today() should not be used in list validations? Or, can you suggest any workarounds?

Comment: You can make the edit yourself. Maybe you can add a thing or two I don't know about list validations! :)